In a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline, how can I retrieve the error message for an SFTP failure?
In a Jenkins Pipeline, when using the SFTP functionality, if a file is not found or there are insufficient permissions, it shows the error "No such file or directory," but the pipeline is still marked as successful. Is there a way to detect this error and stop the pipeline?
+ sftp -i **** -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user01@192.168.10.1:/file
Connected to 192.168.10.1
Changing to: /file
sftp>                                                     put ABC.txt
stat ABC.txt: No such file or directory
sftp>                                                     bye

[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

Finished: SUCCESS


Thank you for the log. Could you share your code? Are you using some plugin? sh step? bat step?
